# Unable to select the records across all pages in Angular DataTables

Tags: jquery, angular, datatables, angular-datatables

Trying to select the checkboxes across all pages, but If we change the page selected records are not appending to the previous selected records. It takes second page records only. Can any one suggest me how to handle to select the records across all pages.

```
 checkboxCheckCount(info: any): void {
    var totalamount = 0;
    $("#firstTable input:checked").each(function() {
      if (info.index != "") {
        totalamount += parseFloat(info.index);
      } else {
        totalamount = totalamount;
      }
    });
    $("#idCheckBoxLabel").text(totalamount);
  }
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/select-pagea-across-all-pages?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, **add** `ChangeDetectorRef` dependency to your component.

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

then **add** `checked` property to all `persons`.

```
this.persons = response.data;
this.persons.forEach(f => (f.checked = false));
```

Then **implement** your `checkuncheckall` method:

```
checkuncheckall() {
    const totalChecked = this.persons.filter(f => f.checked).length;
    const target = totalChecked !== this.persons.length;
    this.persons.forEach(f => (f.checked = target));
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}
```

Your `rowCallback` is no longer needed.

**Changed** `checkboxCheckCount` function which will always update dynamically to get total amount.

```
get checkboxCheckCount() {
    const selectedPersons = this.persons.filter(f => f.checked).map(m => m.id);
    const totalAmount = selectedPersons.length
      ? selectedPersons.reduce((sum, current) => sum + current)
      : 0;
    return totalAmount;
  }
```

**In HTML:**

Setting the **count**:

```
<div>Count::<span>{{ checkboxCheckCount }}</span><div>
```

**Toggling individual row checkboxes**:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxCls" [value]="person.checked" [checked]="person.checked" name="id" (change)="person.checked = !person.checked"></td>
```

See **working demo** at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/select-pagea-across-all-pages-aj7hge?file=app/app.component.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It is working fine :)

Comment: HI Zunayed Shahriar, Is there any solution like we can select only current page records instead of across all pages, please suggest me if any.